# How to Change Logging Levels of OpenEJB in Apache TomEE

Tags: logging, openejb, apache-tomee

How can I set the logging levels of OpenEJB components running inside TomEE? I want to see the debug logging statements from the source code of `org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig`.

I tried modifying conf/logging.properties and adding a logging.properties file in WEB-INF\classes of my WAR but I can't find the right combination and I'm not even sure these are the right files to modify/create.

Comment: Thanks for the edit DataNucleus. I wanted to ask a different question at first involving JPA and forgot to remove the tag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add:

```
OpenEJB.startup.config.level=FINE
```

to `conf/logging.properties`

<strike>This doesn't work when launching the server from Eclipse for some reason.</strike>

To make it work in Eclipse, add this to the server's launch configuration:

```
 -Djava.util.logging.config.file="<put catalina.base path here>/conf/logging.properties"
 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

Source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_enable_the_JULI_logging_in_a_Tomcat_5.5_Server_instance.3F